# ADF PySpark Notebook Check if Directory Exist on Azure Storage Account

Tags: pyspark, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have notebook using PySpark. A section that I am struggling with is to check if a directory in a container exist on Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2.

[image]

If the directory exist I can read the underlying data files into dfStaging and also check if the dfStaging contains any data. In this case I want to merge this dfStaging with another dfLanding into dfMerge.

Else I just work with dfLanding

However if the directory does not yet exist I need to know so I  handle this if statement correctly

```
for row in collectPartition: 

dfLanding = df.filter(col("_partition") == row["_partition"])

dfStaging = spark.read.load(row["_location"], format='parquet', schema=dataSchema) #ERROR: IF the location does not yet exist an error occurs

dfLanding.printSchema()
dfStaging.printSchema()

if dfStaging.count() == 0:   
    #first time - create new dataset
    dfLanding.write.mode('overwrite').parquet(row["_location"])

else:
     #second time - merge dataset
    dfLanding = dfLanding.withColumn('_source',lit(1))
    dfStaging = dfStaging.withColumn('_source',lit(2))
    
    dfMerge = dfPartition.union(dfStaging)
    partition = Window.partitionBy("RECID").orderBy(col("_source"))    
    dfMerge = dfMerge.withColumn("_version",row_number().over(partition))

    dfMerge = dfMerge.filter(col("_version") == 1)
    dfMerge = dfMerge.drop("_source")
    dfMerge = dfMerge.drop("_version")
    dfMerge.write.mode('overwrite').parquet(row["_location"])
```

Comment: what exactly is your goal?what is the error your facing?

Comment: I am trying merge two data frames DF1 and DF2. DF1 is existing data that could or could not exist. DF2 is new data that will exist. I want to establish whether a directory and underlying parquet files exist. If so then I need to do a merge ... else I can just write DF2 to the location.

Comment: add your code in the question and error you are facing?

Comment: Are you using azure databricks notebook?

Comment: I am using notebooks inside of Azure Synapses Workspace.

Comment: @LordRofticus You are using Azure synpase and using the storage account with in the synapse ADLS to check and create new directories with the data from dfLanding or merge the data when the directories already exist?

Comment: @dileeprajnarayanthumula yes I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try below code for folder checking and based on that execute your code.

```
for row in collectPartition:
    stg_dir = row["_location"].replace(row["_partition"],"")
    dirs = [i.path for i in mssparkutils.fs.ls(stg_dir)]
    if row["_location"] in dirs:
        print(row["_location"])
        dfStaging = spark.read.load(row["_location"], format='parquet', schema=dataSchema)
        if dfStaging.count() == 0:
            #first time create dataset code
        else:
            #merge data code
    else:
        #handle if dir not exists.
        mssparkutils.fs.mkdirs(row["_location"])
        print(row["_location"]+" created")
```

To handle when folder does not exist is to create folder and write it.

File in container.

[image]

Output:

[image]

So, you can use these `if-else` blocks in your merging and creating dataset code.

Comment: If there are no data files in the newly created directory, will "reading it into a dataframe" not fail?

Comment: Not fail until you specify schema. You will get data count `0`.